# Is there a way to randomize a Lindenmayersystem?

Tags: random, fractals, lindenmayer

I'm trying to draw a classical Koch-Curve using the lindenmayersystem, but everytime a line segment is transformed there should be a 50/50 chance of it to be flipped left or right. The goal is to generate a realistic looking coastline made out of the directions for Koch-Curve-constructions.
I'm really not familiar with the random function of tikz, so my attempt doesn't work at all:

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Koch curve}{
  \symbol{A}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
  \symbol{B}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
  \rule{A -> A+A--A+A}
  \rule{B -> B-B++B-B}
  \rule{S -> (random(A,B))}
  }

  \tikz\draw[lindenmayer system={Koch curve,angle=60,axiom=S,order=4}]lindenmayer system;

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: I almost got it now, the only remaining problem is that after each sequence (four lines with a pike) the angles stay randomized. That causes the overall segments of the curve to not follow the initial construction rule for the Koch-Curve (A+A--A+A):

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Koch curve}{
  \symbol{A}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}

  \symbol{a}{\pgfmathrandom{0}{1}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0%
\def\pgflsystemrightangle{120}\def\pgflsystemleftangle{60}%
\else\def\pgflsystemrightangle{-120}\def\pgflsystemleftangle{-60}\fi}

  \symbol{+}{\pgflsystemturnleft}
  \symbol{-}{\pgflsystemturnright}

  \rule{A -> Aa+A-A+A}
  }

  \tikz\draw[lindenmayer system={Koch curve,axiom=A,order=2}]lindenmayer system;

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last segment that goes to the top left should lust go straight to the right just like the first segment. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, this is built-in. There are some keys that start with `randomize`. At the lower-level, the commands start with `\pgflsystemrandomize…` which are already used by `\pgflsystemdrawforward` and for example `\pgflsystemturnleft`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel ok thank you very much! Do you by any chance know where I can find information on how to use those commands correctly?

Comment: The [manual itself](https://tikz.dev/library-lsystems) explains them pretty good. That said, I've digged around a bit and there is no built-in way to randomnize between `A` and `B` inside a rule. I've also tried making a symbol that calls another symbol based on a random number but that's not that easy because we would need to mess with the parser. But it wouldn't be hard to do random stuff inside a symbol. `\pgfmathrandom{0}{1}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0 \pgflsystemdrawforward\else\pgftransformrotate{180}\pgflsystemdrawforward\fi`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks again! I'll try to implement that later, hopefully It'll work!

Comment: Ok 7 hours in and I still can't do it. I tried to change around the angles but that doesn't seem to be the solution.